# disabling checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am disabling the ID checkbox using following jquery

## jQuery

```
$('.ColVis_collection button').first().find('input').attr("disabled", true);
```

## html

This code is inside another button, which when clicked gets activated like a dropdown.

```
<div class="ColVis_collection TableTools_collection" style="display: block; position: absolute; opacity: 1; top: 102px; left: 274px; width: 449px;">
    <button class="ColVis_Button TableTools_Button" style="width: 449px;">
        <span>
            <span class="ColVis_radio">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            </span>
            <span class="ColVis_title">
                <span>
                    id
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
    <button class="ColVis_Button TableTools_Button" style="width: 449px;">
        <span>
            <span class="ColVis_radio">
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
            </span>
            <span class="ColVis_title">
                <span>
                    name
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

The first button with span id gets disabled using the jquery and blurred showing that it is disabled but it can be clicked i.e. checked/unchecked. Am I missing something?

## Edit:

I am using jQuery datatables colvis feature, which lets you hide/unhide the table columns

As you can see in this image, the checkbox seems disabled but can be checked/uncheked

[image]

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? in more recent versions of jQuery `.attr("disabled","disabled")` should be `.prop("disabled",bool)`

Comment: I'm unclear as to what the problem is. In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PBhPJ/) the ID checkbox is disabled.

Comment: @j08691, ya but neither other checkbox can be clicked, but when used with Datatables colvis feature, the checkbox can be checked/unchecked, and Yes by the jQuery I've posted, its seems like its been disabled but can be clicked.. I am using jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 11):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to set the disabled property

```
$('.ColVis_collection button').first().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled", true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ZDMs/)

[Attributes vs. Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Answer (score 4):

try some thing like this:

```
 $("input").prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a read only attribute as well:

```
$('.ColVis_collection button').first().find('input').attr("disabled", true).attr("readonly", true);
```

That might sort you out . . .

Answer (score 0):

Didn't figured out what happened. May be I'll look later. Ended up hiding the first button i.e.

```
$('.ColVis_collection button').first().attr("hidden", true);
```